# Cache source code fetched via CMake FetchContent in GitHub Actions

Tags: cmake, github-actions

I've got a CMake-based project in which I heavily rely on [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) to retrive multiple libraries (source code). Downloading all the libraries may take time which I want to save when compiling on a CI runner (GitHub Actions).

I saw there's a [cache](https://github.com/actions/cache) action, how I can use that to cache the fetched source code?

As a bonus, It might be helpful to cache the **compiled** code of these fetched libraries as well. It that possible somehow?

Comment: `how I can use that to cache` There's that [long documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows) that explains how to use it, and it's linked from README of the project you linked. What have you tried? What exactly is unclear to you? `It that possible somehow?` Yes.

Comment: The questions is more about the FetchContent feature. I'm trying to understand what should I cache and where to retrieve it so that the build system (CMake) will behave.

Comment: `FetchContent` just downloads the file to `BINARY_DIR` as set by `FetchContent_Populate` - the `ExternalProject_Add` is used to _really_ download it. Just cache the destination where it downloaded - it will be restored. But generically, it seems you would want to just cache the whole build dir, just be sure to properly manage cache values in cmake - they are tricky.

Comment: I see. I don't want to cache the whole build dir because I actually was clean build. The problem with caching only the `FetchContent` download destination is that it's inside the build directory which doesn't exist before invoking CMake. And retrieving the cache afterwards, well, will make CMake fetch the content.

Answer (score 0):

CMake doesn't provide any such functionality.

For that reason I have developed my own solution at https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/dlcache.

What you need to do is to replace the URL parameters with local file paths of the locally cached files. That's what https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/dlcache-cmake is providing.